# Где нужно использовать Singlenton?

Tags: php, mysql

Интересуют конкретные случаи.
Для БД и отдельных классов.
Как создать его я понял ,а где применять нет.В каких случаях нужно единственное подключение к БД и один экзкмпляр объекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, для доступа к объекту сессии. Ну, или для доступа к тому-же самому подключению mysql, которое в тегах указано.
Получится что-то типа:

```
Db::Connection()->query("SHOW TABLES");
```

Подобный подход обычно используется во всяких ОРМах, для того, чтобы не создавать 100500 подключений к одной БД.

При работе с сессиями удобно проверять, авторизован ли пользователь, от которого пришел запрос, или нет)

```
Session::instance()->isAuthorized(); // true if authorized, else false.
```

Это примеры из возможных велосипедов.

В Yii, к примеру, синглтоном является само приложение(Доступно через `Yii::app()`).

Короче, синглтоном следует делать те объекты, которые в вашем приложении должны иметь только 1 инстанс.

Comment: Кстати, плохая затея параллелить подключения к БД? Напр. планируются простые-быстрые запросы, и один длинный, который может себе выполняться какое-то время отдельно, асинхронно.

Comment: спасибо nolka

Comment: Если мой ответ вас удовлетворил, отметьте его как правильный(нажмите галку слева)

Comment: @sergiks - вы можете скрыть логику connection pool'a внутри внтури вашего синглтона